# Div won't expand with content

Tags: css, html, overflow

I've searched this site all over and can't find the solution to my problem. First of all here's an image of my problem. (The div's with the "sssss" should expand vertically). So the content of the div should go to the next line when it hits the border. Any advice is very well appreciated.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAq9r.png)

Here is my code.

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <LINK rel=StyleSheet href="styles/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-center">
            <div id="logo">Logo</div>

            <div id="search-user">
                <form action="" id="SearchUser">
                    Search User: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">           </asp:TextBox>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Burndown Chart</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>


   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f3f4f9; 
font-family: Verdana;
border: 0px;
}

#header 
{
width: 100%;
background-color: #0066CC;
}

#header-center 
{
margin: 0 auto;  
width: 800px;
height: 80px;
}

#logo 
{
float: left;
margin-top: 13px;
height: 50px;
font-size: 40px;
color: White;
font-weight: bold;
}

#search-user 
{
float: right;
color: White;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 25px;
}

#nav-menu 
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-top: 1px solid #003366;
clear: both;
}

#nav-menu ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 48px;
background-image: url(../images/menu-ul-bg.png);
}

#nav-menu ul li
{
display:inline;
line-height: 50px;
}

#nav-menu ul li a
{
padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
color: Black;
font-size: 14px;
}

#nav-menu ul li a:hover
{
color: White;
}

#wrapper 
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/CSS/hyphens.
You most likely wouldn't have many words that runs more than 25 characters. Proper words will break up properly and flow downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have one long string that the browser won't break on its own. The height will adjust automatically if you break it up into [**smaller words**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RWTZ9/1/), if you use the CSS3 **[word-break](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RWTZ9/)** or **word-wrap** property.

Ex: `word-break:break-all;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your #wrapper styling:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

This will brake long words like the 'ssssssssssssssssssssssss' one and make it go along divs width.